# Updating PictureBox control every one minute in windows form

Tags: vb.net

I am new to dotnet. I have an application with one login screen and three other screens.
On login user can go to any of the other three screens by selecting the options.
On all three screens i have a Picture box which i need to update the Image every one minute based on some logic.Can you please help me on how to do it.

Note: I have a base form, all the forms are inherited from Baseform
      User can go only to one form at a time 
      Using VS2003

Comment: can you upgrade to visual studio express 2008? 2003 is a bit old. but the solution would be the same, use a timer

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
Private WithEvents myTimer As New Timer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    myTimer.Interval = (60 * 1000)
    myTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub myTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles myTimer.Tick
    myPicturebox.Image = MyLogicthatreturnAnImage
End Sub
```

Comment: Can i have a thread in my main page and can this thread update picture box in each form

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Timer component.
Here's the code in C#:

```
var timer=new Timer()
timer.Tick+=DrawPicture;
timer.Interval=60000;// its in miliseconds
```

Now every time you want to start the timer you just set its enable property to true:

```
timer.Enable=true;
```